# Do tabs in Apple Safari get their own processes?

Tags: macos, process

It appears they do when I pull up the process manager ...

[image: imgur - process list from OSX]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, tabs in Safari get their own processes. It's been that way for quite a few years now but it wasn't always that way.

Comment: Any ideas why the gmail tab takes .5 GB of memory?